# Edit footer via customizer

Tags: theme-development, themes, theme-customizer, footer, add-theme-support

I am creating my own theme. I would like to edit the footer in the customizer. I was able to enable the custom logo etc. but I can't find a solution how to enable the footer button in the customizer.

How can I enable the button in the customizer to edit the content of the footer? I haven't found anything with `add_theme_support()`. Is there another way to edit the footer in the backend?